# Replacing Text in a PDF with Aspose PDF Cloud using Python

Tags: python, pdf, aspose, aspose.pdf

I've been trying to replace text from a [PDF](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf) file using Aspose PDF Cloud

```
!pip install asposepdfcloud

import os 
import asposepdfcloud 
from asposepdfcloud.apis.pdf_api import PdfApi

pdf_api_client = asposepdfcloud.api_client.ApiClient(
    app_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    app_sid='xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

pdf_api = PdfApi(pdf_api_client) 
filename = '/content/sample_data/dummy.pdf' 
remote_name = '/content/sample_data/dummy.pdf'

pdf_api.upload_file(remote_name,filename) 

text_replace1 = asposepdfcloud.models.TextReplace(old_value='PDF',new_value='XXX',regex='true') 
text_replace_list = asposepdfcloud.models.TextReplaceListRequest(text_replaces=[text_replace1]) 

response = pdf_api.post_document_text_replace(remote_name, text_replace_list) 
print(response)
```

However, when I try running the above code it yields an error

```
ApiException: (404)
Reason: Not Found
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Mon, 08 Mar 2021 08:21:44 GMT', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'Kestrel', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=2592000'})
```

Not sure why this error pops up after a successful upload `{'errors': [], 'uploaded': ['dummy.pdf']}`

Please Advise

Comment: You may check your cloud storage to verify the file path, it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be solved by,

**Replacing**

```
remote_name = '/content/sample_data/dummy.pdf'
```

**With**

```
remote_name = 'dummy.pdf'
```

Comment: So it means you uploaded the file to cloud storage root instead of "/content/sample_data" folder.

Comment: Yeah but I don't really see how adding a different path solves the issue